# SwipeToDismiss weird behavior when deleting item that is not last in LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've tried to implement the SwipeToDismiss behavior in my app and it works perfectly when I try to delete the last or the only item in the LazyColumn. However, if I try to delete an item that is not the last one the next one will swipe to start but not entirely off the screen.

https://streamable.com/4v2i0d

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TasksListLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onNavigate: (UiEvent.Navigate) -> Unit,
    viewModel: TaskViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val tasks = viewModel.tasks.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.uiEvent.collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                is UiEvent.ShowSnackbar -> {
                    val result = scope.launch {
                        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                            message = event.message, actionLabel = event.action, duration = SnackbarDuration.Long
                        )
                    }
                    if (result.equals(SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed)) {
                        viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvent.OnUndoDeleteTask)
                    }
                }
                is UiEvent.Navigate -> onNavigate(event)
                else -> Unit
            }
        }
    }
    Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = { viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvent.OnAddTask) },
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add a task")
            }
        },
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text("Planner") }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                )
            )
        },
    ) { padding ->
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(padding)
                .padding(horizontal = 12.dp),
            verticalArrangement = spacedBy(12.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 12.dp)
        ) {

            items(tasks.value) { task ->
                val currentTask by rememberUpdatedState(newValue = task)
                val dismissState = rememberDismissState(confirmValueChange = {
                    if(it == DismissValue.DismissedToStart) {
                        viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvent.OnDeleteTask(currentTask))
                    }
                    true
                })
                SwipeToDismiss(state = dismissState, directions = setOf(DismissDirection.EndToStart),
                    background = { },
                    dismissContent = {
                        TaskCard(
                            task = task, onEvent = viewModel::onEvent, modifier = modifier
                        )
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the issue I needed to add a key to the LazyColumn.

Changed from this:

```
items(tasks.value) {}
```

To this:

```
items(items = tasks.value, key = { task -> task.hashCode()}) {}
```